# If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, then $m_A(\lambda)=0$

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $m_A(\lambda)$ is the minimal polynomial of $A_{n\times n}$.

1. Show that if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, then $m_A(\lambda)=0$
2. Show that $m_A(x)$ of a diagonalizable matrix $A$ divides the characteristic polynomial $f_A(x)$.

For the second question, I was thinking we could use the fact that if $p(x)$ is a polynomial such that $p(A)=0$, then $m_A(x)$ divides $p(x)$. I think this requires a proof of number 1, though, since a diagonalizable matrix $A$ will have the eigenvalues on the diagonal, but I'm not really sure.

Comment: The second one is actually true in general, by Cayley-Hamilton. But for a diagonalizable matrix, the characteristic polynomial and minimal polynomial are easy to find, so you can check it directly.

For 1, what happens when you apply $m_A(A)$ to an eigenvector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hints:** For the first question: let $x$ be an eigenvector.  Consider $m_A(A)x$.  For the second: yes, that will work.

Comment: What does $m_A(A)x$ represent?

Comment: $m_A(A)$ is the matrix that comes out of plugging $A$ into the polynomial $m_A$.  Take that matrix, and multiply it by $x$.

Comment: OK, I think I got #1. For #2, what is $m_A(x)$ of a diagonal matrix $A$? Why is it zero?

Comment: Note that for any diagonal matrix
$$
D = \pmatrix{d_1\\&\ddots\\&&d_n}
$$
and any polynomial $p$, we have
$$
p(D) = \pmatrix{p(d_1)\\&\ddots\\&&p(d_n)}
$$

Comment: When we say that "matrix $A$ is diagonalizable," are we really saying that $A$ can be written as a diagonal matrix where its eigenvalues are on the diagonal? I thought it just meant that $A$ could be factored into $SBS^{-1}$, where $B$ is the diagonal matrix with eigenvalues on the diagonal.

Comment: You're correct. Note that we have $p(SBS^{-1}) = Sp(B)S^{-1}$.

Comment: Which would mean that $p(A) = Sp(B)S^{-1} = 0$, correct? Why does $p(SBS^{-1}) = Sp(B)S^{-1}$? Also, how does this lead us to the characteristic polynomial of $A$, $f_A(x)$?

Comment: @Carley actually, we should probably stick to the other comment's approach: $f_A(A) = 0$ by the Cayley Hamilton theorem.  It follows that $m_A$ divides $f_A$.

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused. Maybe I need to reread this chapter.